# Extracting a specific list from a NavigableMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm working with a Navigable map defined as follow `NavigableMap<Date,T>`. `T` can be anything, most of the time it will be a number. The date part is more ambiguous. As I'm working with time series, it can be expressed as a day, an hour, a minute,... It is just a time-stamp following a certain period. If the period is a day, each key will be a different day. If the period is a hour, each key will be a different hour, etc.

I would like at one point to extract a subMap of this NavigableMap, being able to query something like "give me the map at a reference date X +/- y periods". In this case, period has to be understand as an Int => give me all the data for the 10-Jul-2014 +/- 3 period of time (i.e. 3 days in that case).

The problem is that map are not really designed to use indexes. I don't want to make hard computation around the key date either (like taking a date, subtracting a number of period, obtaining a new date, and finally extracting a subMap). A period remains a period whether it is second, hours, or days.

What would be a neat way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: I would think the cleanest way to do it would be to either extend NavigableMap or create a NavigableMapHelper. Where you would have a method subMap(Date,offset) that returned a subset of the data for the given +/- offset. Somewhere you'll have to figure out what +/- 3 period translate to in order to get the boundaries.

Comment: *I don't want to make hard computation around the key date either*: too bad, because that's obviously what you need to do. I don't see how it's such a "hard computation", especially if you use the new Java 8 time API, or joda time if on a previous JDK.

Comment: I should have added the following precision... There could have "holes" in the key set where, for a given period of time, there are no data. I don't really control the way data are sent. this is asynchronous, and if there are no data during a period of time, I just don't receive anything. Shifting of "one period" is just the same as shifting by one index in an array.

Comment: To be even more precise, I'm using a TreeMap to store my data `private NavigableMap<Date,T> map = Collections.synchronizedNavigableMap(new TreeMap<Date,T>(new BasicDateComparatorIncreasing()));` So objectively, my data are still ordered. I could just produce an array and lookup for the index. I'm just wondering if there is another way to do this. Maybe using Stream in java 8 ?